# VBA convert Excel file to text when sending mail outlook

Tags: vba, excel

how can i convert the activeworkbook that i am working on , while sending a mail in outlook ?
This code has like attachments .xlsx file , but i want it in text , how can i change it ? 
Thanks

```
 'send mail code
                Set ol = New Outlook.Application
                Set olmail = ol.CreateItem(olMailItem)
                With olmail
                    .To = "test@outlook.com"
                    .Subject = objetText
                    .Body = "testing"
                    .Send

                .attachments.Add activeworkbook.fullname
                End With
            End sub
```

Comment: Not clear what you want exactly. A workbook can contain multiple worksheets. So how shall those worksheets be represented in text? Also, if only a range in one worksheet is meant, then how shall this range be represented in text? Or do you mean a range represented as rich text table?

Comment: this workbook have just 1 worksheet and it is just about numbers and names , so i want to convert the excel to txt so that the other can receive just those information from the text file @AxelRichter

Answer (score 2):

With MS Office you can copy an Excel cell range in the clipboard and paste this into an Outlook mail body if that mail body is in rich text format and you are using Word editor. The cell range will be converted into a rich text table while this process.

This can also be accomplished by code:

```
Sub emailer()

 Set oOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

 olMailItem = 0
 Set oOlMItem = oOlApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

 'get Excel cell range which shall be in the mail
 Set oWB = ActiveWorkbook
 Set oWS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
 Set oRange = oWS.Range("A1:C10")

 oRange.Copy ' Range is now in Clipboard

 With oOlMItem

  .Display

  .To = "email@email.com"
  .Subject = "Subject"

  Set oOlInsp = .GetInspector
  Set oWdDoc = oOlInsp.WordEditor ' get Word Document from the MailBody

  olFormatRichText = 3
  .BodyFormat = olFormatRichText ' change to RichTextFormat

  Set oWdRng = oWdDoc.Paragraphs(oWdDoc.Paragraphs.Count).Range
  oWdRng.InsertBefore "This is before the Excel table."
  oWdRng.InsertParagraphAfter
  oWdRng.InsertParagraphAfter

  Set oWdRng = oWdDoc.Paragraphs(oWdDoc.Paragraphs.Count).Range
  oWdRng.Paste ' paste Excel range from Clipboard

  oWdRng.InsertParagraphAfter

  Set oWdRng = oWdDoc.Paragraphs(oWdDoc.Paragraphs.Count).Range
  oWdRng.InsertBefore "This is after the Excel table."


 End With

 Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: hello , thanks for your help , i just have a problem in : Set oWdContent = oWdDoc.Content , error 91 Object variable or With block variable not set (Error 91) , what it the problem?

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce. Works for me with Office 2007 and 2016. But the line `Set oWdContent = oWdDoc.Content` is an artifact and not necessary. Furthermore I have updated the code so that it works also if Outlook is not opened already. I had not testet this before since my Outlook is opened always. But if it is not, the code will only work correct if at least one Outlook window is visible. So now the code will `.Display` the mail item first befor continuing.

Answer (score 0):

You can only convert 1 worksheet to text, so I'm assuming this is what you are trying to accomplish. Copy the sheet to a new workbook (so you can continue working with the current workbook as xlsm), save that as text then use the save location for the string you're using for attachments.add

```
Dim wbkthis As Workbook
Dim wbkNew As Workbook

Set wbkthis = ActiveWorkbook 
'So we can come back here
Set wbkNew = Workbooks.Add 
'New book to copy sheet to

wbkthis.Sheets("relevantsheetname").Copy Before:=wbkNew.Sheets(1)

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'Supress overwrite and close alerts, you may not want this

wbkNew.SaveAs "savelocation\Mybookname.txt", xlText 
'use this same string with your attachments.add code
wbkNew.Close

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
wbkthis.Activate ' Go back to original file
```

Answer (score 0):

I am certain that Axel's answer is probably what you need but since you asked about converting to it to text and then putting it in, this will do that. The formatting will look terrible of course.  Make sure that (in the VBE) you go into tools/references and place a check next to Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim DataObj As MSForms.DataObject
Set DataObj = New MSForms.DataObject
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    ws.UsedRange.Copy
DataObj.GetFromClipboard
strbody = DataObj.GetText(1)

With NewMail
  .SUBJECT = "Test Mail"
  .From = """Sender"" <sender@email.com>"
  .To = "receiver@email.com"
  .CC = ""
  .BCC = ""
  .TextBody = strbody
End With
```

Comment: Thank you so much !